# Set keyboard shortcuts that use the Windows key (Mod4) in Fedora 15?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora

In Fedora 14, I set a custom keyboard shortcut to maximize windows to the left and right part of the screen using <kbd>[image: WIndows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> (e.g., <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow left</kbd>). However, in Fedora 15, this doesn't seem to work. Why is this happening? Is there a fix?

Comment: Have you reconfigured since your update?

Comment: What do you mean? I tried adding the shortcuts again, if that's what you mean.